# How do I restart mediawiki on namecheap's shared hosting?

Tags: mediawiki, namecheap

I just made a change for my mediawiki configuration in the LocalSettings.php file but I don't know how to restart mediawiki so that it picks up the configuration change.

I installed mediawiki using softaculous on namecheap's shared hosting Stellar plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply changes you make in the LocalSettings.php by going to the LiteSpeed Web Cache Manager in CPanel and using the "Flush All" button.